# Small Business Server and external Linux DHCP/DNS Server

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, windows-sbs-2003, vyatta

I have SBS2003 in my network as a domain controller. I want to setup Linux Vyatta router with DHCP server and DNS forwarding (relay) enabled. How to do that? When I enable DHCP/DNS server clients will receive vyatta DNS and I think clients will not be able to connect to my domain. Am I right?

Comment: I dont know vyatta specifically but most router/firewall systems let you specify your own DNS servers - set that to point to your wintendo server, then it should work just fine. Or, being a linux based device, just add a record pointing your wintendo-domain to that box.

Comment: vyatta does support externat DNS and DHCP servers, I'm running such configuration in all installations I use vyatta

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you'd want to do this in light of the fact that you're running SBS, which is intended to fill the DHCP/DNS roles, but if you must then make sure that the DNS server you choose is capable of hosting DNS zones and supports SRV DNS records (rather than being just a DNS resolver\forwarder such as a router or firewall would be). The DC must register AD specific SRV records with the DNS server and the clients must be able to find those records when querying the DNS server. Otherwise you're going to have a non-functioning domain.

Comment: You scared me. So this is not enought, what Stokkeland said? I can specify the IP address of SBS to be returned in response to the DNS query. What you said is unfeasible for me.